# How to hide ls -l output in bash script when used with time command?

Tags: bash

I am writing a bash script to store the individual values of minutes and seconds.
However, I am unable to do so.

```
TIMEFORMAT='%3lR'
exec 3>&1 4>&2
cmd='ls -l / >/dev/null 2>&1'
var=$( { time $cmd  1>&3 2>&4; } 2>&1 )  # Captures time only.
exec 3>&- 4>&-
echo 'Get the var'
echo $var
min=$(echo $var | awk -F 'm|s' '{print $2}')
echo $min
```

The output shows ls -l / which I don't want.
Next, I don't understand what is exec 3>&- 4>&-. I copied this from other stack overflow answers. I don't understand what is the use of { inside the (  bracket.

Comment: The output you're seeing is from the `var=$(` line. `$var` itself is null. It seems like the output of `time` can't be captured, cause I tried redirecting every descriptor to `/dev/null` at the end of that line and none of them made any difference. But I'm not an expert on redirection.

Comment: Copy/paste your script into http://shellcheck.net and fix the issues it tells you about then post a question about your fixed script if you still have one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
TIMEFORMAT='%3lR'
var=$({ time ls -l / 2>&1 > /dev/null; } 2>&1)
echo 'Get the var'
echo ${var}
min=$(echo ${var} | awk -F 'm|s' '{print $2}')
echo ${min}
```